# googleUser.getBasicProfile is not a function after login

Tags: javascript, google-signin, google-oauth

I am trying to implement Google login on my web app.

I can get the popup to appear to ask me to authorise the app. However, when this calls onSignIn I recieve:

```
googleUser.getBasicProfile is not a function
```

and I'm not really sure why? Any help would be appreciated.

code:

Index.html:

```
  <span id="signinButton">
        <span
            class="g-signin"
            data-callback="onSignIn"
            data-clientid="myidHere"
            data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
            data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
            data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
        </span>
```

app.js

```
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
   var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
   console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
   console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
   console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
   console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());

   var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

 }

    (function() {
     var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
     po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
   })();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to call getBasicProfile() of google to google signin on only button click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331428/how-to-call-getbasicprofile-of-google-to-google-signin-on-only-button-click)